# передача данных из класса в фрагмент android

Tags: android, android-fragment

Есть класс, который парсит json-строку и сохраняет данные из нее в строки в своем классе, и есть фрагмент, в который нужно передать эти строки.

Сам parsedata.class вызывается из фрагмента

```
public class ParseData extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    public static String LOG_TAG = "my_log";
    public static String sharedValue;
    public Socket client;
    public String resultJson = "";
    private String ip = "192.168.1.162";
    private int port = 7777;

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {
            client = new Socket(ip, port); // connect to the server
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(),true);
            out.println(params[0]);
            InputStream is = client.getInputStream();
            StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                buffer.append(line);
            }
            resultJson = buffer.toString();
            client.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return resultJson;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String strJson) {
        super.onPostExecute(strJson);
        JSONObject dataJsonObj = null;
        String illumination = "";
        try {
            dataJsonObj = new JSONObject(strJson);
            JSONArray friends = dataJsonObj.getJSONArray("data");

            for (int i = 0; i < friends.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject friend = friends.getJSONObject(i);
                JSONObject contacts = friend.getJSONObject("weather");
                String cel = contacts.getString("temperature");
                String humidity = contacts.getString("humidity");

                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Температура: " + cel);
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Влажность: " + humidity);

                sharedValue = cel;

            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

И код фрагмента в котором нужно получить эти строки:

```
public class LoftFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {
    Button button;
    TextView temp;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.loft_layout, container, false);
        temp = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.twmpt);
        button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn1);
        button.setOnClickListener(this);
        String s = ParseData.sharedValue;
        temp.setText(s); // отобразить полученную строку
        return view;
    }
}
```

Каким путем лучше реализовать передачу данных?

Answer (score 2):

Вам надо создать отдельный класс который будет загружать данные с сервера, но который ничего не будет знать о том в каком потоке он работает. Примерная структура такого класса будет такая(псевдокод):

```
public class WeatherLoader {

    public Result loadData(String someParam){
        //код по загрузке данных, в котором нет явного указания в каком потоке работать
    }    
}
```

`Result` здесь является произвольным типом, поставьте вместо него то, что вы сами захотите.

Потом в вашем фрагменте создаете `AsyncTask` и загружаете в нем данные:

```
public class LoadData extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Result> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        WeatherLoader loader = new WeatherLoader();
        return loader.loadData(params[0]);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Result result) {
        // делаем с результатом что хотим
    }
}
```

Ну и вызывайте этот `AsyncTask` в своем `Activity/Fragment` как обычно.

Мой вам совет, после того как освоите `AsyncTask` изучите другие способы взаимодействия с сервером, коих сейчас очень много, т.к. `AsyncTask` не лучший способ организации такого взаимодействия. Посмотрите, например, на библиотеку [RoboSpice](https://github.com/stephanenicolas/robospice). В связке с [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) они способны значительно облегчить жизнь.